# Re-interpolate a DataFrame so that it aligns with another (very related) DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have two dataframes with the same column names, `['x', 'y']`.  None of the data represent time.  Both these dataframes have the same number of rows.  Their `'x'` columns are ever-so-slightly misaligned.

Dataframe A, which I consider the "golden" (or theoretical, if you will) data set, has the following entries:

```
x: [0, 1, 2]
y: [0, 1, 2]
```

Dataframe B, which could be some data I gathered from the electronics bench, has the following entries:

```
x: [0, 1.03, 1.98]
y: [0, 1.05, 2.03]
```

What I want to do is to re-align Dataframe B so that it represents the data at the same `x` points that Dataframe A has.  To illustrate, I want to transform Dataframe B so that it looks like this:

```
x: [0, 1,    2]
y: [0, 1.02, 2.05]
```

How did I get to the values for `y`?  A picture would best explain the similar triangles I used to do it:

[image: similar triangles]

Does `pandas` have a built-in function to do this? Are there libraries that help me do this? (else I'll have to write this from scratch)

#### Update 1

It looks like `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` would solve this problem elegantly.

Comment: If `x` and `y` are the colums, does it mean that each dataframe consists of just one triangle? Or do you have other columns to match values from the different dataframes?

Comment: @Aryerez there are no other columns but `x` and `y` only on each dataframe. I want to align dataframe B to dataframe A's `x` column so that I can compare them fair and square.

Comment: What do you mean by similar? Would `3.1` be similar to `2` given absence of three? If not, maybe simple rounding and matching one `DataFrame` with another based on key created from `(x,y)` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can think of in `pandas` is `reindex().interpolate()`. Playing with `method` option of `interpolate()` I think this might be what you want:

```
new_x = sorted(pd.concat((df1.x,df2.x)).unique())
df2.set_index('x').reindex(new_x).interpolate(method='krogh')
```

Output:

```
             y
x             
0.00  0.000000
1.00  1.019233
1.03  1.050000
1.98  2.030000
2.00  2.050751
```